# When using a header logo in Ionic, the browser tab shows html

Tags: html, header, ionic-framework

I have a logo image in my header using Ionic.

```
<ion-view title="<img class='title-image-pic' src='./img/MyImg.jpg'>">
```

It looks great, but the browser tab shows the html element. How do I work around this and have the browser tab display my title instead of:

```
<img class='title-image-pic' src='./img/MyImg.jpg'>
```

Thank you for any advice you can give.

Comment: "my title"?  what do you want to be displayed if not the image?

Comment: It doesn't display the image, it displays the html element.

Comment: i tried your code. it worked correctly, so your problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your title in **index.html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <!-- Other things -->
  </head>
  <!-- Body and stuff -->
</html>
```

Then you can set the image in your own template, using the [`ion-nav-title`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavTitle/) directive:

```
<ion-nav-view>
  <ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>
      <img class='title-image-pic' src='./img/MyImg.jpg'>
    </ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content>
      Some super content here!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: Aha! This was it - I needed to add the title in the ion-view (view-title) that would appear in the browser tab. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `'ion-nav-title' is not a known element`

Comment: @RomainFournereau Which version of Ionic are you using?

Comment: 3.1.6, I decided to use `this.app.setTitle`

Comment: This question was for Ionic 1.